# Code First Migration wants to [re]create the table for one entity that is within a different DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

Suppose I have 3 entities: A, B and C;

```
public class A // Target entity
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual ICollection<C> C { get; set; } // Navigation to C
}

public class C
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; } // Navigation to A
}
```

...and currently a single context: X

```
public abstract class Context : DbContext
{
    protected const string CONNECTION_NAME = "some_connection_name";
    protected const string SCHEMA_NAME = "dbo";

    public Context() : base(CONNECTION_NAME)
    {
        Database.Log = message => Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SCHEMA_NAME);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}

public class X : Context
{
    public DbSet<A> A { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm adding a second context (Y) and hence the entity C points to A through a navigation property, `Code First Migrations` wants to [re]create a table for the entity A, however it already exists.

```
public class Y : Context
{
    public DbSet<B> B { get; set; }

    public DbSet<C> C { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

The second context should explicitly [Ignore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.ignore(v=vs.113).aspx) the `A` entity:

```
public class Y : Context
{
    public DbSet<B> B { get; set; }

    public DbSet<C> C { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CConfiguration());

        modelBuilder.Ignore<A>(); 

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to doing so, because the more entities are added as dependencies (navigation properties for entities within a different context), the bigger is the headache.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I always try to keep class models belonging to different contexts apart from each other. When I need an entity in multiple contexts I rather duplicate the class than reusing a class (like: a `User` entity in the core business context and an `AuthorizationUser` entity in the authorization context, all only having the associations they need in that specific aggregate of the application but mapped to the same table).